# UIButton setTitle: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, swift2

Confused why my buyButton does not accept:

```
buyButton?.setTitle("Downloaded", forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
```

It was crashing at this point until I set the conditional and it obviously is not seeing a value.

In my ViewDidLoad, I have set:

```
buyButton.setTitle("Buy", forState: .Normal)
```

This is working fine, and then I reset the title again in my buy function:

```
@IBAction func buyButtonAction(sender: AnyObject)
{    
        //print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
        print("buyButton Pressed")
    buyButton.setTitle("Purchasing...", forState: .Normal)

}
```

again it works fine. But...

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedDownloads downloads: [SKDownload])
{
    print("in the downloads")

    for download in downloads as [SKDownload]
    {
        switch download.downloadState
        {
        case SKDownloadState.Active:
            print("Download progress \(download.progress)")
            print("Download time = \(download.timeRemaining)")

            break
        case SKDownloadState.Finished:

            print("download completed")

            buyButton.setTitle("Purchased", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

blah blah code shortened here...
```

when I call setTitle again after the file has downloaded buyButton looks like its Deallocated?

I've set the buyButton to strong and checked the button is connected properly and read through numerous posts but still can't find the answer. Its not massively important to the app but I'm annoyed that I don't understand why.

My previous app in Objective-C would easily accept numerous changing of button title. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Side-note: Casting of distinct types is completely useless (*as SKPayment*, *as [SKDownload]*) since the compiler knows the type.

Comment: check your button outlet ...is it properly connected or not...

Comment: yes, its connected properly - I disconnected and reconnected it twice!

Comment: got that Vadian - thanks!

Comment: is paymentQueue method called asynchronously ???? if yes can you confirm paymentQueue is getting called on main thread ??? If not try setting button title on main thread :)

Comment: paymentQueue is being called async according to Apple. So I tried calling ...dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.buyButton.setTitle("Downloaded", forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
        } ...this didn't change anything. But I think that is the root cause. Any other ideas?

Comment: So you can confirm that the button itself is nil when you try to set its title - the first line of code in your post is misleading since it cannot possibly crash, ever. Have you tried tracking down where exactly the button gets deallocated? I assume you also made sure it's not declared `weak` after disconnecting/reconnecting?